# "If necessary " in clause of condition

Tags: clauses, adverbial-phrases

> **If necessary**, you can contact me on the weekend.

Some information of the subordinate clause is omitted.

How does "if+ adjective" work?
Is there a rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand this as "If it is necessary,..."  With the pronoun implied by context. It's normally only suitable for "telegraphese" or rather unnaturally shortened expressions.

> If ready, you can begin. ("If you are ready,..." or "If it is ready,..." according to context)

> When hot, add the tea.  ("When it is hot,..." or from context "When the water is hot,...")

This pattern works well with participles:

> When running, try to drink water.

> If tired, take a break.

But these are all intentionally shorter than would be "natural" in regular conversation.